# django: gettext and coercing to unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, gettext

I have following code in my django application.

```
class Status(object):

    def __init__(self, id, desc):
        self.id = id
        self.desc = desc

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.desc

STATUS = Status(0, _(u"Some text"))
```

When I try to display some status (or even coerce it to unicode), I get:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, __proxy__ found
```

Could anyone explain me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `_()` function from Django can return a `django.utils.functional.__proxy__` object, which is itself not unicode (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/unicode/#translated-strings). Python does not call `unicode()` recursively, so it's an error for your Status object to return the `__proxy__` object directly. You need to make the `__unicode__` method `return unicode(self.desc)`.

Note that this is specific to Django; Python's own `gettext` doesn't return these proxy objects.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that @thomas-wounters solved your issue, but for others who might have a similar issue - please check if you are not using `ugettext_lazy`:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

in that case, you must cast output to str/unicode:

```
unicode(_('translate me'))
```