# Unicode issue in Django

Tags: django, unicode, unicode-string

I seem to have a unicode problem with the `deal_instance_name` in the Deal model.

It says:

> `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, __proxy__ found`

The exception happens on this line:

```
return smart_unicode(self.deal_type.deal_name) + _(u' - Set No.')  + str(self.set)
```

The line works if I remove `smart_unicode(self.deal_type.deal_name)` but why?

Back then in Django 1.1 someone had the same problem on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133508/django-gettext-and-coercing-to-unicode) I have tried both the `unicode()` as well as the new `smart_unicode()` without any joy.

What could I be missing please?

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Deal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)      
        self.deal_instance_name = self.__unicode__()      

    deal_type           = models.ForeignKey(DealType)
    deal_instance_name  = models.CharField(_(u'Deal Name'), max_length=100)    
    set                 = models.IntegerField(_(u'Set Number'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.deal_type.deal_name) + _(u' - Set No.')  + smart_unicode(self.set)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u'Deal')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Deals')
```

Dealtype:

```
class DealType(models.Model):    
    deal_name           = models.CharField(_(u'Deal Name'), max_length=40)
    deal_description    = models.TextField(_(u'Deal Description'),     blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.deal_name) 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u'Deal Type')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Deal Types')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `smart_unicode` part has nothing to do with your issue:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
stuff = u'abc' + ugettext_lazy(u'efg')
```

Would raise the exact same issue.

That's basically because `ugettext_lazy(u'efg')` will not return an `unicode` string, but a `__proxy__`, which will raise an error when you do `u'abc' + ugettext_lazy(u'eg')`.

You would get the exact same issue with: `u'a' + 1`.

You can solve this issue using:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
stuff = u'abc {0}'.format(ugettext_lazy(u'efg'))
```

Alternatively, you could force `ugettext_lazy(u'efg')` into an `unicode` object using `unicode(ugettext_lazy(u'efg'))`.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I do that to the return of `__unicode()__`, correct ?

Comment: @Kave yes, replace `smart_unicode(self.deal_type.deal_name) + _(u' - Set No.')  + smart_unicode(self.set)` with `u'{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.deal_type.deal_name, _(u' - Set No.'), self.set)`

Comment: Perfect. I solved it similar to your suggestion, is this also ok? Seems to be working:  `return u'%s%s%s' % (self.deal_type.deal_name, _(u' - Set No.'), self.set)`

Comment: @Kave Yes, it works too! (But you should be using `str.format` in newer code! ;) )

Comment: ahh thanks for correction. I learned Django/Python from an old Django 1.0 book. :)